# How can I set the c variable to that if entered then it should print "hello world 3" or if not entered then only the upper two should be printed?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

This is a program to take the input at runtime from the user and print hello world depending on the arguments entered. The user can print 2 hello world. However the third hello world is conditional depending if the c value is entered or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 unsigned int a, b, c;


        a = strtoul(argv[1], 0, 0);
        b = strtoul(argv[2], 0, 0); 
        c = strtoul(argv[3], 0, 0); 

        int *p= NULL;//initialize the pointer as null.

        printf("\n first no %d \n ", a);
        printf("\n second no %d \n ", b);

        if ( c == *p)
        {
                    printf("\n third no %d \n ", c);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

1. Suppose I run the program as ./hello 1 2 -> This would print "hello
   world 1" "hello world 2".
2. And if I run the program as ./hello 1 2 3
   -> This would print "hello world 1" "hello world 2" "hello world 3".
3. How can I correct my program to get the desired effect?

Comment: You need to check `argc` to get the number of arguments. You must do this before you put `argv[x]` into `strtoul`. If you don't have enough arguments, `argv[x]` will contain `NULL` or even point beyond the limits of `argv` array. Both situations cause undefined behaviour. If you do this check, you also have the answer for your question.

Comment: Use a loop instead of hard-coding the `argv` indexes. `for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)` and then print `argv[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter `argc` of the `main` function represents the number of arguments passed to the program, so you can check the value of `argc` to determine the behavior of your program.

(For instance, if you run the program as `./hello 2 7 1 8`, then the value of `argc` will be `5`.)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        printf("hello world %s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```